# Basic authentication error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5, basic-authentication

I'm using IIS for hosting my website using asp.net mvc, the authentication is in "basic authetication mode" when ever I'm going to access my website I'ts going to promt me to login .and when I click the cancel button or the (x) the error show! HOW can I solve this problem.. I what that everytime i cancel the basic authentication of my website i want to redirect to  other page for error or specific pag[THE ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrQb8.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `customErrors` section in `Web.config` to redirect users when "401.2 Unauthorized" happens (see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx)). For example:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm" mode="RemoteOnly">
      <error statusCode="401.2" redirect="UnauthorizedPage.htm"/>
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: same I copy and paste this solution, same error. Would like to stay in the same page everytime i cancel my basic authentication